# Infinite Scrolling in ext-js with directjngine

Tags: java, javascript, json, extjs

First of all I ask you to be lenient with me: I'm just a poor ext-js and javascript newbie...

I'm trying to adapt to my needs the [infinite scroll grid example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.html) in ext-js. I defined in sencha ext-js the following store:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.M2MResources', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'Ext.direct.*', //  use ext-direct for binding
    model: 'AM.model.M2MResource',
    autoLoad: true,

    paramsAsHash:false,
    autoSave: false,

    pageSize: 25,
    // allow the grid to interact with the paging scroller by buffering
    buffered: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',
        api: {
            // create  : undefined,
            read    : M2MResourceServlet.getM2Mresources,
            // update  : undefined,
            // destroy : undefined 
        },      
        extraParams: {
              total: 100
        },
        root: 'data',
        fields: [{name:'label'}, {name:'address_unique'}, {name:'address_network'}, {name:'status'}],
        paramOrder: 'page, start, limit',
        reader: {       
            type: 'json',           
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        },
        writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
            encode: false,
            writeAllFields: true,
            listful: true
        }
        )
    }
});
```

with this directJNgine server counterpart:

```
public class M2MResourceServlet {
    public static class ResourceData{       
        public String label;
        public String address_unique;
        public String address_network;
        public String status;
    }

    public static class DirectStoreResult{
        ResourceData[] data;
        public int totalCount;
        public boolean success = true;

        public DirectStoreResult(ResourceData[] data, int totalCount) {
            super();
            this.data = data;
            this.totalCount = totalCount;
        }
    }

    static int counter = 0;
    @DirectMethod
    public DirectStoreResult getM2Mresources( Integer page, Integer start, Integer limit ) {
        ArrayList<ResourceData> result = new ArrayList<ResourceData>();

        // fill result list...

        DirectStoreResult r = new DirectStoreResult(result.toArray(new ResourceData []{}),limit);
        return r;
    }
}
```

Then I specified the following model:

```
Ext.define('AM.model.M2MResource', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name:'label' },
        {name:'address_unique' },
        {name:'address_network' },
        {name:'status' }
     ]
});
```

With that I would like to load data into the following grid:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.resgrid.M2MResources', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.m2mresources',

    title: 'All Resources Here',    

    verticalScrollerType: 'paginggridscroller',

    store: 'M2MResources',

  initComponent: function() {

      console.log('initComponent function in View has been called...');

      this.columns = [
                      {header: 'friendly name',dataIndex: 'label',flex: 1, sortable: true},
                      {header: 'address unique', dataIndex: 'address_unique',flex: 1},
                      {header: 'address network', dataIndex: 'address_network', flex: 1},
                      {header: 'node status',dataIndex: 'status',flex: 1}
                      ];

      this.callParent(arguments);

      Ext.getStore('M2MResources').guaranteeRange(0, 100);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, it seems the store never loads data: the grid panel shows the "loading..."  symbols and no data item are shown. I suspect the issue is in the json returned by my direct method. Client-side I get the following json data records:

[image: data records returned by the ext-direct java method]

Could you please suggest how to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the rational answer to this problem can be found [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?247059-Paged-Grid-Using-a-directjngine-Back-end). Basically, the server side direct method must be of the form

```
@DirectMethod
public PartialResult<ResourceData> getM2Mresources(int start, int limit) {
        ResourceData[] m2mResources = ...
    //...
        return new PartialResult<ResourceData>(Arrays.asList(m2mResources), 
    m2mResources.length);
}
```

where PartialResult class is the following:

```
public class PartialResult<T> {

    /** the partial result set */
    private Collection<T> result;

    /** the size of the complete result set */
    private int total;

    public Collection<T> getResult() {
       return this.result;
    }

    public int getTotal() {
       return this.total;
    }

    public void setResult(Collection<T> result) {
       this.result = result;
    }

    public void setTotal(int total) {
       this.total = total;
    }

    public PartialResult(Collection<T> result, int total) {
       super();
       this.result = result;
       this.total = total;
    }
```

}

and I added some getters in ResourceData class as in the original example.

The js store is

```
Ext.define('AM.store.M2MResources', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.DirectStore',
    requires: 'Ext.direct.*', //  use ext-direct for binding
    model: 'AM.model.M2MResource',

    autoLoad: true,
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 20,
    purgePageCount: 0,
    leadingBufferZone: 60,
    trailingBufferZone: 0,

    constructor : function(config) {
        config = config || {};

        config.proxy = {
            type: 'direct',
            directFn : M2MResourceServlet.getM2Mresources,
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'result'
            },
            paramOrder: 'start,limit',
            paramsAsHash: false
        };

        this.callParent([config]);
    },

    toString: function() {
        return 'M2MResources: count = ' + this.getCount() + ', totalCount = ' 
                + this.getTotalCount();
    }
});
```

Apparently, this is doing exactly what I wanted to do. So thank you Adam Davis! Anyway, I would appreciate if someone could explain why the `directFn` element must be used instead of `api`...

Answer (score 0):

The response data doesn´t match with your reader configuration. You have configured you reader with a **root: 'data'** but what I can see in the response it there is no data node. The expanded node you show is: **root: 'result.data'**. I cannot see the properties **successProperty** nor **totalProperty** neither.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! I modified the two `root: 'data'` into `root: 'result.data'` but still nothing... I also checked the two successProperty and totalProperty: they are at the end of the list, after the data node, like that: `result:                                                       data:[...]
success: true
totalCount: 100`

Comment: But your data is nested in one bigger data structure! Which should it take? record[0], record[1], ...., record[n]? Why are you returning that huge resultset when what you want is only one of all those entries? Return what you need and fix your reader, that´s all.